# Dynamically loading database information into a html/php page

Tags: php

EDIT: My issue was using deprecated functions with an updated PHP version but for anyone trying the same thing with PHP 5.5 or lower follow the accepted answer

I'm looking to be able to fill a table with information from my database. I am fairly new to PHP web development and I am kinda stuck here at the moment

loader.php

```
<?php   
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Couldn't Connect");

mysql_select_db("dbName") or die("Couldn't find database");

$query = "SELECT * from dbTable";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $value1 = $row['value1'];
        $value2 = $row['value2'];
        $value3 = $row['value3'];
        $value4 = $row['value4'];

        $values = "<tr><td>".$value1."</td><td>".$value2."</td><td>".$value3."</td><td>".$value4."</td></tr>";
    }
?>
```

page.php

```
<?php
    require 'loader.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Title</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>1st Value</th>
        <th>2nd Value</th>
        <th>3rd Value</th>
        <th>4th Value</th>
    </tr>
        <?php $values ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to be able to load the $values data into below the heading inside the table in page.php. It seems like this should work but something is not correct.

If anyone could give me some insight to why this isn't working, it would be greatly appreciated.

John

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. The SQL query is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy! Ok, if you are new to php, then this is a good chance to learn some good practices first. First of all, the php code you have written is deprecated. Use PDO instead. Here is a  [good tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059).

Secondly make use of a framework but this is not necessary. It basically comes with lot of good features. So in the long run, you will end of writing less code and its easy to maintain.

Thirdly as others have suggested, now you know what is the error in your code.

EDIT:

In your case, please change the code to this:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Couldn't Connect");

mysql_select_db("dbName") or die("Couldn't find database");

//new edit below
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from dbTable");
$values = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $value1 = $row['value1'];
    $value2 = $row['value2'];
    $value3 = $row['value3'];
    $value4 = $row['value4'];

    //notice the '.' below.
    $values .= "<tr><td>".$value1."</td><td>".$value2."</td><td>".$value3."</td><td>".$value4."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: I am new to developing webpages with php not php in general. I've already worked with PDO, Slim and Ajax with an application I made. I wanted to get the information working this way (as I was following a tutorial for another part of this) before I deconstructed it and moved it into PDO form. But I have tried adding in the echo to no avail.

Comment: Oh ok I see. Then in that case, i have re-written your code. It was correct. You just have to concatenate the values.

Comment: Tried the changes, nothing changed in the webpage. Would it have anything to do with the PHP version I am running? I am running PHP 5.6.8 atm.

Comment: There you go. You have your own answer. Yes ! `mysql_connect` has been deprecated since PHP 5.5.0. So yes those db functions wont work.

Comment: Okay, looks like I'm doing it as PDO from the get go, thanks for the help

Comment: One last question. Why did mysql_connect work with a login system but not with this? It was all using the same PHP verison

Comment: Technically it should not work. But however, thanks for asking that. I found an error on my code. There was no `mysql_query`  (i have edited the code). So your query was actually not getting executed at all. I do not have a solid answer to your question as of now but I will figure it out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change  $values  to  echo $values  in page.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a variable $values, you need to use echo.

```
 <?php echo $values ?>
```

EDIT

You need add: `$query = mysql_query($query);` and edit sql + add $values.
Result:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Couldn't Connect");

mysql_select_db("dbName") or die("Couldn't find database");

$query = "SELECT * from `dbTable`";
$query = mysql_query($query);
$values = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $value1 = $row['value1'];
    $value2 = $row['value2'];
    $value3 = $row['value3'];
    $value4 = $row['value4'];

    $values .= "<tr><td>".$value1."</td><td>".$value2."</td><td>".$value3."</td><td>".$value4."</td></tr>";
}
```

Try this.